# Gradients don't change over steps - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorboard

I am facing this problem for a couple of days now, and I think I am doing the right approach but I want to make sure.

I am training 4 conv layers and two fully connected layers on top of them. The model in tensorflow is as follow:

- Conv1: 64 filters, 7x7 kernel size, leaky relu activation function, [He et al kernel initializer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852v1.pdf), bias initializer 0.001.
- MaxPooling
- Conv2: 96 filters, 5x5 kernel size, leaky relu activation function, He et al kernel initializer, bias initializer 0.001.
- MaxPooling
- Conv3: 96 filters, 5x5 kernel size, leaky relu activation function, He et al kernel initializer, bias initializer 0.001.
- MaxPooling
- Conv4: 64 filters, 3x3 kernel size, leaky relu activation function, He et al kernel initializer, bias initializer 0.001.

I use a custom EMD loss function, which computes the loss correctly. And I use an Adam Optimizer as it follows:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=.01)
grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss_tensor)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads, global_step)
```

I do not use `optimizer.minimize()` because I want to print the gradients in tensorboard.

In the `tf.Session()` I do the following steps:

1. Initialize the iterator.
2. Initialize global varaibles.
3. Loop minimizing the loss.

In the loop I do the following operation:

```
_, summary, loss_res, logits_res = sess.run([train_op, merge, loss_tensor, logits])
```

The error decrease, and the weights slightly change over the steps, but the gradients are constant. I don't know why this is happening or where can be my error. I attach some screenshots of the Tensorboard panel:

[Main graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOXWx.png): Here is the main graph with the model as explained before.

[Gradients histograms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt8oG.png): They only changes in the first step.

[Weights and bias histograms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5nRa.png): They have a small change.

Thanks in advance! If you need more information don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: Have you tried clipping gradients before applying them? Or adding batch normalization layers?

Comment: I haven't clipped the gradients, but in the histogram they have 0 mean so they don't seem so be so big. I have initialized the weights with the distribution that He et al propose in their paper. For example for a conv layer with 3x3 filter I use a 0 mean initializer with (2/(3*3))^(1/2) standard deviation. Do you mean I should clip the gradients to prevent them to be zero?

Comment: Even with means of zero it's possible for large gradient entries to show up and cause problems. It's fairly standard to [clip gradients to a norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_global_norm) of say 1-5. The network you described sounds good, so the things I would try, in order, are 1) a reduced learning rate, 2) gradient clipping, 3) [batch normalization layers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167).

Comment: Thanks argx. I am going to try the things you recommended. I'll let you know!